# How to implement Solr or SolrJ bound query?

Tags: solr

I want to use a query like:

```
sql(select name where id > 10 and id < 100 )
```

by using Solr or in SolrJ, but do not know how to implement? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a range query, as described in [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax). Basically, you collect all relevant documents by using a query range and then select the name field. The syntax is something like:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=id:[10 TO 100]&fl=name`

(You will need to escape the URL).

Comment: Thanks!
For examples, My index have 3 field:title, x and y , and I want to query like: SQL(select title where x>10 and x < 100 and y > 20 and y < 300), how to do by using  Solr range query?

Comment: You need to combine two range queries (for the x and the y) using AND default. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams as to how to do this. Also, if you want the ranges to be non-inclusive (e.g. x>10 instead of x>=10) you need to use a curly bracket { instead of a square one [